# The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer Sharepoint Provider Hosted App

Tags: iis, sharepoint, certificate, sharepoint-apps

I created an app by using the following tutorial:

http://www.luisevalencia.com/2014/07/23/prepare-environments-sharepoint-provider-hosted-apps/

The app works perfectly if there are no sharepoint calls, I meant a response.write with hello world works.

But, if I add some sharepoint stuff like printing out the name of the user, I got a The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

            using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
                Response.Write("Hello World");

            }
```

I get the following error on the logs.

```
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Failed to authenticate request, unknown error. Exception details: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTrustedIssuerNameRegistry`1.GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken, String requestedIssuerName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler.GetIssuerNameFromIssuerToken(JsonWebSecurityToken token)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler.GetIssuerName(JsonWebSecurityToken token)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken token, Boolean isActorToken)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken token, Boolean isActorToken)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPJsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TryExtractAndValidateToken(HttpContext httpContext, SPIncomingTokenContext& tokenContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.ConstructIClaimsPrincipalAndSetThreadIdentity(HttpApplication httpApplication, HttpContext httpContext, SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: I suppose I did something wrong on the certificate, creation, or import.!

Comment: Steve Peschka has some awesome troubleshooting tips and tricks here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/11/01/more-troubleshooting-tips-for-high-trust-apps-on-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the SharePointContextFilterAttribute on the method? That filter handles the authentication bits from the request context.